# phpinfo only displays a blank page on nginx

Tags: nginx, php

I'm currently learning Nginx, and trying to get phpinfo to be displayed.
But it only displays a blank page like this.
[image: phpinfo blank]

The below is what I have made sure / tried so far.

- php socket is at the correct location

```
find / -name *fpm.sock
/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

- php file has been created properly

```
root@nginx-fundamentals:/sites/demo# cat info.php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

- the user for nginx process is the same as the one for php

```
root@nginx-fundamentals:~# ps aux | grep nginx
root        1056  0.0  0.3   8720  3212 ?        Ss   Jun20   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  104677  0.0  0.3   9140  3684 ?        S    Jul06   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      112008  0.0  0.2   8160  2496 pts/0    S+   04:03   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root@nginx-fundamentals:~# ps aux | grep php
root       11018  0.0  1.0 195484 10496 ?        Ss   Jun21   1:52 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data   11020  0.0  0.4 195872  4756 ?        S    Jun21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data   11021  0.0  0.4 195872  4756 ?        S    Jun21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      112010  0.0  0.0   8160   736 pts/0    S+   04:03   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

- the content of the conf file should be fine

```
root@nginx-fundamentals:/etc/nginx# cat nginx.conf
user www-data;
events {}
 
http {
    include mime.types;
    server {
 
      listen 80;
      server_name XX.XXX.XXX.117;
 
      root /sites/demo;
      index index.php index.html;
 
      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
 
      location ~\.phps$ {
        # Pass php requests to the php-fps service (fastcgi)
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      }
    }
}
```

- When the path is not specified, it displays the default page.
  [image: Default page]

What am I doing wrong?
What else should I investigate?

Comment: I'm fairly sure `location ~\.phps$ {` will not match for `info.php`. is the extra `s` a typo?

Comment: Oh, yeah! That was the culprit and it began to work fine once I fixed that. Thank you :D